# Is there a news module in drupal 7?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I would like to have news posted on my frontpage, but only the Title of the news in a list, and then if you click at one of them you could go to a separate page or maybe show that news-article directly on the frontpage (by expanding the title with the rest of the text). Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It'd be much simpler if you can create your own view using the [Views module](http://drupal.org/project/views).

Here are some [video tutorials](http://drupal.org/node/1351076) to get you started with views.

Hope this helps... Muhammad.

Answer (score 0):

Use simplenews module to create news.

https://drupal.org/project/simplenews

but for better custom news use views as Muhammad Reda has said.